# Why do I keep getting a Terminator error for Python Turtle?

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception, python-turtle

I'm writing a simple console application where you type commands. One such command includes: `draw`. `draw` uses the Python turtle module and some functions from my own module. Here's my main code (some of it's blocked out because it doesn't handle the `draw` command):

```
import os
import datetime
import webbrowser
import random
import turtle
import functions as fn  # grabs functions from functions.py
import text_colors as txt

is_running = True

while is_running:
        [some code...]
        elif commands[0].lower() == "draw":
        try:
            t = turtle.Turtle()
            if commands[1].lower() == "square":
                fn.draw_rect(t)
            elif commands[1].lower() == "circle":
                fn.draw_circle(t)
            elif commands[1].lower() == "triangle":
                fn.draw_triangle(t)
            else:
                txt.print_red("Invalid shape!")
            turtle.done()
        except IndexError:
            txt.print_red("No shape was provided!")
        [some more code...]
```

And here's the module where my functions are defined:

```
import turtle
import time


def draw_rect(t):

    for i in range(0, 4):
        t.forward(100)
        t.right(90)

    time.sleep(3)
    turtle.clearscreen()


def draw_circle(t):

    t.circle(50)

    time.sleep(3)
    turtle.clearscreen()


def draw_triangle(t):

    t.forward(100)

    for i in range(0, 2):
        t.left(120)
        t.forward(100)

    time.sleep(3)
    turtle.clearscreen()
```

When I run it, the console runs it just fine, and when I type `draw square` to open Turtle and draw a square, it runs just perfect. However, when I close Turtle and retype `draw square`, I get this big fat error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "kshell_base.py", line 209, in <module>
    t = turtle.Turtle()
  File "C:\Users\keega\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\turtle.py", line 3813, in __init__
    RawTurtle.__init__(self, Turtle._screen,
  File "C:\Users\keega\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\turtle.py", line 2557, in __init__
    self._update()
  File "C:\Users\keega\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\turtle.py", line 2660, in _update
    self._update_data()
  File "C:\Users\keega\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\turtle.py", line 2646, in _update_data
    self.screen._incrementudc()
  File "C:\Users\keega\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\turtle.py", line 1292, in _incrementudc
    raise Terminator
turtle.Terminator
```

I've tried appending `turtle.done()` to the end of each function, but yet it still gives me this exception. Please help! I still need it to be able to draw and this is not a bug I want to have in my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out! You have to use `turtle.TurtleScreen._RUNNING = True` in the code. Here's my new code (main code):

```
import os
import datetime
import webbrowser
import random
import turtle
import functions as fn  # grabs functions from functions.py
import text_colors as txt

is_running = True

while is_running:
        [some code...]
        elif commands[0].lower() == "draw":
            try:
                if commands[1].lower() == "square":
                    t = turtle.Turtle()
                    fn.draw_rect(t)
                elif commands[1].lower() == "circle":
                    t = turtle.Turtle()
                    fn.draw_circle(t)
                elif commands[1].lower() == "triangle":
                    t = turtle.Turtle()
                    fn.draw_triangle(t)
                else:
                    txt.print_red("Invalid shape!")
            except IndexError:
                txt.print_red("No shape was provided!")
        [some more code...]
```

And here's my new module code:

```
import turtle
import time


def draw_rect(t):
    for i in range(0, 4):
        t.forward(100)
        t.right(90)

    time.sleep(3)
    turtle.clearscreen()
    t.screen.exitonclick()
    turtle.TurtleScreen._RUNNING = True


def draw_circle(t):
    t.circle(50)

    time.sleep(3)
    turtle.clearscreen()
    t.screen.exitonclick()
    turtle.TurtleScreen._RUNNING = True


def draw_triangle(t):
    t.forward(100)

    for i in range(0, 2):
        t.left(120)
        t.forward(100)

    time.sleep(3)
    turtle.clearscreen()
    t.screen.exitonclick()
    turtle.TurtleScreen._RUNNING = True
```

Now, if you close the turtle window after typing `draw square` or something, and retype
a `draw` command, it does it without complaining.

Comment: This strange code really helps.

`
s = turtle.Screen()
...
s.exitonclick()
turtle.TurtleScreen._RUNNING = True
`

Answer (score 0):

Just for info:

Using the Idle Python shell:

While trying out some basic turtle stuff, I found, when I started a window to do something, it works fine the first time.

If you try to run the same again, you get this terminator (shades of Arnold) error:

> myApp() Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/usr/lib/python3.10/idlelib/run.py", line 578, in runcode
> exec(code, self.locals)   File "<pyshell#31>", line 1, in    File "<pyshell#28>", line 3, in myApp   File "", line 5, in
> getscreen turtle.Terminator

So I tried entering this in Idle:

```
turtle.TurtleScreen._RUNNING = True
```

After that, myApp() works again, no problem